# Update issue with data-bound Listbox and PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, listbox, propertygrid

This is part of my AOI class (nothing special about it):

```
class AOI : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Guid _id;
    private string _name;
    private string _comment;

    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public string Comment
    {
        get { return _comment; }
        set
        {
            _comment = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Comment");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_name.Length > 0)
        {
            return _name;
        }
        else
        {
            return _id.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

I keep them in a `BindingList<AOI>` which is bound to a `ListBox`. In the `SelectedValueChanged` event of the `ListBox` I assign the selected object to a `PropertyGrid`, so that the user can modify the `AOI`.

This works fine except for the Name field (which is displayed in the `ListBox` (see `ToString()` above)).

When I edit the name field using the `PropertyGrid`, the `ListBox` is updated correctly. But in the `PropertyGrid,` the `Name` field (just the value) is cleared as soon as I press enter. The correct (modified) value appears when I set the cursor to another field in the `PropertyGrid`.

What is the easiest workaround to handle this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of the PropertyGrid.

This can also be reproduced with the designer within the Visual Studio. Simply select a control and change its minimum size to a larger value than the current one. If you take a look into the grid, the value in the size property won't be updated till you select it within the grid.

If some rows won't update correctly normally one of these two options will help:

- Reattach the object to the PropertyGrid by calling `propertyGrid.SelectedObject = myObject`
- Force the grid to redraw itself by calling `propertyGrid.Invalidate()`